# Can node.js detect when it is closed?

Tags: node.js

I want to know if it is possible to detect when a node.js process is closed through clicking the 'X' on Windows. If so then how. I have tried `process.on("exit");` but that did not work.

Comment: As in closing the browser window or closing a window in Windows that runs Node ?

Comment: window in which node is running.

Comment: Once Node is no longer running, it can't detect that it's not running.

Comment: So it doesn't make a call when it is closing?

Comment: It does fire an event when the process is ending, but not sure if you catch it when you force it to close by closing the window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catch [SIGHUP](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events)

```
/*
 * Run this code and close the Window before the 10 seconds
 */
var x = setTimeout(function() { console.log('hello world') }, 10000);

process.on('SIGHUP', function() {
  console.log('About to exit');
  process.exit();
});
```